# Continuations in Clojure

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, scheme, continuations

I read somewhere where rich hickey said:

> "I think continuations might be neat
>   in theory, but not in practice"

I am not familiar with clojure.
1. Does clojure have continuations?
2. If no, don't you need continuations? I have seen a lot of good examples especially from [this guy](http://okmij.org/ftp/). What is the alternative?
3. If yes, is there a documentation?

Comment: Your question title doesn't seem to have much to do with the question text.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When talking about continuations, you’ll have to distinguish between two different kinds of them:

- First-class continuations – Continuation-support that is deeply integrated in the language (Scheme or Ruby). Clojure does not support first-class continuations.
- Continuation-passing-style (CPS) – CPS is just a style of coding and any language supporting anonymous functions will allow this style (which applies to Clojure too).

Examples:

```hs
-- Standard function
double :: Int -> Int
double x = 2 * x

-- CPS-function – We pass the continuation explicitly
doubleCPS :: Int -> (Int -> res) -> res
doubleCPS x cont = cont (2 * x)
```

```lisp
; Call
print (double 2)

; Call CPS: Continue execution with specified anonymous function
double 2 (\res -> print res)
```

Read [continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) on Wikipedia.

I don’t think that continuations are necessary for a good language, but especially first-class continuations and CPS in functional languages like Haskell can be quite useful ([intelligent backtracking example](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2005/10/11/amb-operator)).

Comment: Regarding the second of your two points, wouldn't tail-call optimisation be required to make CPS usable in the general case? Consider a standard function, which you wrap in a "while (!aborted)" block to make it repeat until aborted. Wouldn't the equivalent use of a CPS-style function be to send it itself as a continuation? Thus you get unbounded recursion and tail-call optimisation would be required. I'm just thinking out loud here, so please tell me if this makes sense :-)

Answer (score 23):

I've written a Clojure port of cl-cont which adds continuations to Common Lisp.

https://github.com/swannodette/delimc

Answer (score 19):

## Abstract Continuations

Continuations are an abstract notion that are used to describe control flow semantics.  In this sense, they both exist and don't exist (remember, they're abstract) in any language that offers control operators (as any Turing complete language must), in the same way that numbers both exist (as abstract entities) and don't exist (as tangible entities).

Continuations describe control effects such as function call/return, exception handling, and even gotos.  A well founded language will, among other things, be designed with abstractions that are built on continuations (e.g., exceptions).  (That is to say, a well-founded language will consist of control operators that were designed with continuations in mind.  It is, of course, perfectly reasonable for a language to expose continuations as the *only* control abstraction, allowing users to build their own abstractions on top.)

## First Class Continuations

If the notion of a continuation is [reified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(computer_science)) as a first-class object in a language, then we have a tool upon which all kinds of control effects can be built.  For example, if a language has first-class continuations, but not exceptions, we can construct exceptions on top of continuations.

## Problems with First-Class Continuations

While first-class continuations are a powerful and useful tool in many cases, there are also some drawbacks to exposing them in a language:

- Different abstractions built on top of continuations may result in unexpected / unintuitive behavior when composed.  For example, a `finally` block might be skipped if I use a continuation to abort a computation.
- If the current continuation may be requested at any time, then the language run-time must be structured so that it is possible to produce some data-structure representation of the current continuation at any time.  This places some degree of burden on the run-time for a feature which, for better or worse, is often considered "exotic".  If the language is hosted (such as Clojure is hosted on the JVM), then that representation must be able to fit within the framework provided by the hosting platform.  There may also be other features a language would like to maintain (e.g., C interop) which restrict the solution space.  Issues such as these increase the potential of an "impedence mismatch", and can severely complicate development of a performant solution.

## Adding First-Class Continuations to a Language

Through metaprogramming, it is possible to add support for first-class continuations to a language.  Generally, this approach involves transforming code to continuation-passing style (CPS), in which the current continuation is passed around as an explicit argument to each function.

For example, David Nolen's [delimc](https://github.com/swannodette/delimc) library implements delimited continuations of portions of a Clojure program through a series of macro transforms.  In a similar vein, I have authored [pulley.cps](https://github.com/positronic-solutions/pulley.cps), which is a macro compiler that transforms code into CPS, along with a run-time library to support more core Clojure features (such as exception handling) as well as interop with native Clojure code.

One issue with this approach is how you handle the boundary between native (Clojure) code and transformed (CPS) code.  Specifically, since you can't capture the continuation of native code, you need to either disallow (or somehow restrict) interop with the base language or place a burden on the user of ensuring the context will allow any continuation they wish to capture to actually be captured.

pulley.cps tends towards the latter, although some attempts have been made to allow the user to manage this.  For instance, it is possible to disallow CPS code to call into native code.  In addition, a mechanism is provided to supply CPS versions of existing native functions.

In a language with a sufficiently strong type system (such as Haskell), it is possible to use the type system to encapsulate computations which might use control operations (i.e., continuations) from functionally pure code.

## Summary

We now have the information necessary to directly answer your three questions:

1. Clojure does not support first-class continuations due to practical considerations.
2. All languages are built on continuations in the theoretical sense, but few languages expose continuations as first-class objects.  However, it is possible to add continuations to any language via, e.g., transformation into CPS.
3. Check out the documentation for [delimc](https://github.com/swannodette/delimc) and/or [pulley.cps](https://github.com/positronic-solutions/pulley.cps).

Comment: It took almost seven years, but we finally have a correct and thorough answer to this question. Excellent! This should become the accepted answer.

Comment: @BenKovitz Thanks.  I debated whether to provide an answer given the age of the question.  Your comment makes me glad I did.

Answer (score 13):

> Is continuation a necessary feature in a language?

No. Plenty of languages don't have continuations.

> If no, dont you need continuations? I have seen a lot of good examples especially from this guy. What is the alternative?

A call stack

Answer (score 7):

A common use of continuations is in the implementation of control structures for: returning from a function, breaking from a loop, exception handling etc. Most languages (like Java, C++ etc) provide these features as part of the core language. Some languages don't (e.g: Scheme). Instead, these languages expose continuatiions as first class objects and let the programmer define new control structures. Thus Scheme should be looked upon as a programming language toolkit, not a complete language in itself.

In Clojure, we almost never need to use continuations directly, because almost all the control structures are provided by the language/VM combination. Still, first class continuations can be a powerful tool in the hands of the competent programmer. Especially in Scheme, continuations are better than the equivalent counterparts in other languages (like the setjmp/longjmp pair in C). [This](http://vijaymathew.wordpress.com/2009/07/22/yaaec-yet-another-attempt-to-explain-continuations/) article has more details on this.

BTW, it will be interesting to know how Rich Hickey justifies his opinion about continuations. Any links for that?

Comment: What are the features that you need to have in order for a language to be "full"?

Comment: It should have been "complete" not "full". When I said "complete" I did not mean Turing complete. I meant the features that people usually expect from "modern" languages. For instance, exception handling using try-catch. Scheme does not provide that, but using first-class continuations you can implement your own exception handling mechanism.

Comment: Good Lispers write programs by growing the language towards the problem. In other words, you transform Lisp into a language that is best suited to solve the problem at hand. This is a big difference between Lisps and other languages. Paul Graham explains this in great detail in his book "On Lisp". I don't know who you are or what you do, but I suppose that you haven't written any significant piece of software in Lisp. Otherwise I wouldn't have to explain this. I maintain my own Scheme and use it daily to solve real world problems.

Comment: BTW, I don't think it is a good idea to ask someone to explain his viewpoint after calling it "inane rambling".

Comment: Re "almost all the control structures are provided by the language/VM combination", you forgot to add that nobody will ever need more than 640kb RAM.

Answer (score 6):

Clojure (or rather `clojure.contrib.monads`) has a continuation monad; [here's an article that describes its usage and motivation](http://www.intensivesystems.net/tutorials/cont_m.html).

Answer (score -1):

Well... Clojure's `->` implements what you are after... But with a macro instead

Comment: I think its a valid answer. The result of one step is passed into input of the next step. The effect is a continuation-type mechanism, achieved through code rewrite

Comment: I don't think this `->` really captures at all what the OP is after.  At best, `->` is similar to the Identity modad.  Now, if you could change `->` to use any arbitrary monad instead, I would agree with you than `->` would be sufficient to express any computation that uses continuations (you could just use the Continuation monad).  But `->`, as implemented in Clojure, provides no way to suspend and resume a computation.  First-class continuations give you -- complete control over which parts of a computation run and when they are run.  This is completely lacking with `->`.